# How to return Multiple element using FastAPI in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, fastapi

I am using FastAPI to build a API to download csv file in parallel I want to show query is running back in the browser which they are using and once the download complete want to display the file down is completed on the browser.

Please guide me how to do this

I am using below code

```
@app.get("/fetch-table-view-api", status_code=200)
async def fetch_table():
    try:
        query = "SELECT * FROM xxxx table;"
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        df = cursor.fetch_pandas_all()
        cursor.close()
        #print(out)
        print("Select completed")
    except Exception as e:
        # conn.rollback()
        print("\n######### There was a problem in selecting data #########################")
        print("Error: " + str(e))
        sys.exit(1)
    return StreamingResponse(
        iter([df.to_csv(index=False)]),
        media_type="text/csv",
        headers={"Content-Disposition": f"attachment; filename=data.csv"},status_code=200
    )
```

Can you please let me how to include it here because process here is query running takes 2 minutes and after that file will be download and I want to display the runtime and download completed on the browser screen

Comment: If you're only looking to display the time the user has waited (and not a percentage done or similar), you can do that purely in JavaScript by incrementing a counter; if you want to actually show progress, you have to have some way of telling how far along in the process your different tasks has come (i.e. is it the query or the csv-conversion or the download that's taking time - how you do it will depend on what you're trying to do).

Comment: I want to show the query execution wait time. other two aspects does not take much time. I want to flash on browser screen like download is completed once after file is download is completed